# Find a value then modify the cell 4 columns to the right with a Yes or a No from a dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open a message box and find a quote number located on `sheet 2, column B`. If found, the message box will ask to update the status of that quote number, which is 4 cells to the right, on column F.

I grabbed a code off another website for another code/button. When I try to use it for this application, it doesn't follow through and modifies the last entry on column F.

I think the line `Soldlr = Ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` needs to be modified to direct it to change the information 4 cells to the right of whatever quote number the message box was able to find.

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateEntry()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range
Dim Sold As String, Soldlr As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Data Entry")

With ws
    strSearch = InputBox("Enter Quote Number To Update", "Update Quote Entry")
    Set aCell = .Columns(2).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                 MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

        Sold = InputBox("Was This Quote Sold?", "Sales Entry", "Yes or No")
        aCell.Offset(0, 4) = Sold
        MsgBox "Quote Number " & strSearch & " Has Been Modified"

    Else

        MsgBox "Quote Number " & strSearch & " Not Found. Try Again"
    End If

    Exit Sub
End With
End Sub
```

I expect to push a button and a message box to appear. That box will ask for a quote number. Once the quote number is entered, it will look for that quote number and ask "Has quote number 'quote number entered' been sold?" with a drop down list of only two possible choices ("Yes" and "No"). Whatever answer is chosen, will overwrite a cell 4 spaces to the right of the quote number found.

Comment: To write to the cell 4 cells to the right of the found cell, use `aCell.Offset(0, 4) = ...`

Comment: Generally I would ask if @chrisneilsen wants to write an answer and you would accept so he can get the rep associated with providing an answer. If he doesn't want to, then please write your own answer and accept. This lets people know that your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't review edits. I guess I'm not on that level. :(

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateEntry()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range
Dim Sold As String, Soldlr As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Data Entry")

With ws
    strSearch = InputBox("Enter Quote Number To Update", "Update Quote Entry")
    Set aCell = .Columns(2).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                 MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

        Sold = InputBox("Was This Quote Sold?", "Sales Entry", "Yes or No")
        aCell.Offset(0, 4) = Sold
        MsgBox "Quote Number " & strSearch & " Has Been Modified"

    Else

        MsgBox "Quote Number " & strSearch & " Not Found. Try Again"
    End If

    Exit Sub
End With
End Sub
```